# Wordpress custom taxonomy not searchable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Have added successfully custom taxonomy to Woo products:

```
$args = array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Companies',
    'singular_name' => 'Company',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Company',
  ),
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui'=> true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'exclude_from_search' => false
);

register_taxonomy( 'companies', 'product', $args );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'companies', 'product' );
```

Problem comes when I try to query this with WP search in search.php:

```
if(have_posts()){
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      echo get_the_ID();
  endwhile;
}
```

Example: `/?search=My Company`

What's the correct approach to this? I tried to flush (update permalinks but without any success). Cannot query the Category taxonomy neither (default Woo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add filters `posts_where`, `posts_join`, `posts_groupby` to add taxonomy in search results like this:

```
function atom_search_where($where){
  global $wpdb;
  if (is_search())
    $where .= "OR (t.name LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish')";
  return $where;
}

function atom_search_join($join){
  global $wpdb;
  if (is_search())
    $join .= "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id";
  return $join;
}

function atom_search_groupby($groupby){
  global $wpdb;

  // we need to group on post ID
  $groupby_id = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
  if(!is_search() || strpos($groupby, $groupby_id) !== false) return $groupby;

  // groupby was empty, use ours
  if(!strlen(trim($groupby))) return $groupby_id;

  // wasn't empty, append ours
  return $groupby.", ".$groupby_id;
}

add_filter('posts_where','atom_search_where');
add_filter('posts_join', 'atom_search_join');
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'atom_search_groupby');
```